# MVC Cascading Dropdown using JQuery AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a drop down list of US states.  When the user selects the state another drop down list of county/parrish is to be populated.  I am pulling the information to populate the county drop down from a stored procedure.  The problem I have is that it is returning object Object for each county and I do not know what to do to correct this.

here is the code in the controller

```
public ActionResult FillCountyList(string State)
{
    Models.CountyList mod = new CountyList();
    mod.TheState = State;
    List<ListCountiesByState_Result> Counties = mod.ListCounties();
    return Json(Counties, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

I have also tried to the following in my controller and it also returns a list showing object Object for each county

```
public JsonResult FillCountyList(string State)
{
    IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Counties = db.ListCountiesByState(State).Select(c => new SelectListItem {
            Value = c.County,
            Text = c.County
    }).ToList();
    return Json(Counties, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Here is the jquery code in the view

```
$('#State').change(function () {
    var stateid = $('#State').val();
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Profile/BackgroundData/FillCountyList',
        type: 'GET',
        datatype: 'JSON',
        data: { State: stateid },
        success: function (result) {
            $('#CountyOrParrish').html('');
            $('#CountyOrParrish').append($('<option>Make Selection</option>'));
            $.each(result, function (i, item) {
                $('#CountyOrParrish').append($('<option></option>').text(item));
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check That your method returns countries correctly. Also change:

```
$('<option></option>').text(item));
```

to:

```
$('<option></option>').val(item.Value).html(item.Text));
```

Comment: I had already tried that.  It still returns object Object for each value

Comment: Have you checked your `FillCountyList` method returns correctly?

Comment: OK i tried with the second controller example and this works!!  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can access your counties properties on javascript just using the "." separator since each item in your result is a json object:

```
$.each(result, function (i, item) {
           $('#CountyOrParrish').append($('<option></option>').text(item.CountyName));
        });
```

Comment: I know it should work but it returns the following message "Intellisense was unable to determine an accurate completion list for this expression.  The provided list contains all identifiers in the file."    And then on the page it shows nothing but empty string for the text.