# Cascading Dropdownlist on the basic scaffolded CRUD within an MVC application

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, cascadingdropdown

#### Some Background:

Hello, I'm a beginning programmer and only learned ASP.net MVC through tutorials a few weeks ago, and I managed to get as far as scaffolding Controllers and Views based on my Models, with entities having relationships with other entities through foreign keys, so not that far lol. Up to this point, I heavily relied on the automatic processes provided to me by Visual Studio 2017, such as my Create Form automatically generating a Dropdownlist populated by data from another table.

#### The Problem:

However, I'm now wrestling with this idea of filtering this dropdownlist based on what I have selected from another dropdownlist, and I learned that the solution that I'm looking for revolves around *Cascading Dropdownlists*. My situation is a lot like the usual Country-State example where the State dropdownlist is populated by what I have selected from the Country dropdownlist. I have already accepted that I must use another language such as jquery/ajax to do this, but all the solutions that I've worked with either looked too different from what I was doing or was too advanced for me. I tried really hard to learn this but I'm afraid I would only end up failing because I only used the built-in scaffolding to set-up my routes, connections, and database. I have already looked and exhausted all my efforts in searching for solutions that has the same background as me but I can't seem to find one.

#### The Application

It's not too hard to reproduce my code, since like I said I only followed the basic instructions in making an MVC application and pretty much all of it was scaffolded. So the general set-up is this:

## Models

*Region Entity (like a Country)*

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace SMOSystemv2.Models
{
    public class Region
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string RegionName { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Province> Provinces { get; set; }
    }
}
```

*Province Entity (like a State in a Country)*

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace SMOSystemv2.Models
{

    public class Province
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }

        public int RegionID { get; set; }

        public virtual Region Region { get; set; }

        public string ProvinceName { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Institution> Institutions { get; set; }
     }
}
```

*Institution Entity (where I'll keep data for institutions such as schools, the region and the province where the school is located are important for me to keep track of)*

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace SMOSystemv2.Models
{

    public class Institution
    {

        public int ID { get; set; }

        public int ProvinceID { get; set; }

        public string InstitutionName { get; set; }

        public virtual Province Province { get; set; }

    }
}
```

## Controllers

The controllers that I have for these entities are basically what the scaffolding would give you from the very beginning, except for a few changes in the InstitutionsController *(see Create, GetRegionList, and GetProvinceList methods)* when I started to implement the solutions I've searched for Cascading Dropdownlists

*InstitutionsController*

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using SMOSystemv2.Models;

namespace SMOSystemv2.Controllers
{
    public class InstitutionsController : Controller
    {
        private SMOSystemv2Context db = new SMOSystemv2Context();

        // GET: Institutions
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var institutions = db.Institutions.Include(i => i.Province);
            return View(institutions.ToList());
        }

        // GET: Institutions/Create
        public ActionResult Create()
        {

            ViewBag.RegionList = new SelectList(GetRegionList(), "ID", "RegionName");

            return View();
        }

        public List<Region> GetRegionList()
        {
            List<Region> regions = db.Regions.ToList();
            return regions;
        }

        public ActionResult GetProvinceList(int RegionID)
        {
            List<Province> provinceList = db.Provinces.Where(x => x.RegionID == RegionID).ToList();

            ViewBag.ProvinceOptions = new SelectList(provinceList, "ProvinceID", "ProvinceName");
            return PartialView("ProvinceOptionPartial");
        }


        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                db.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
}
```

## Views

Like before, I haven't change much of the scaffolding except for adding a Dropdownlist for Region, a partial view, and a script which I've watched from this youtube video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mNfoQe7XLkM as shown below,

*Institution/Create*

```
@model SMOSystemv2.Models.Institution

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Add</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm())
{

    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Institution</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Province.RegionID, "RegionID", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">

    @if (ViewBag.RegionList != null)
    {

                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Province.RegionID, ViewBag.RegionList as SelectList, "--Select Region--", new { @class = "form-control", @id = "RegionDDL"})
    }

            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Province.RegionID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProvinceID, "ProvinceID", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">

    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ProvinceID, new SelectList(""), "--Select Province--", new { @class = "form-control"})

                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProvinceID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>


        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.InstitutionName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.InstitutionName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.InstitutionName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>



@section Scripts {

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")

<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $("#RegionDDL").change(function () {

                var regionID = $(this).val();
                debugger
                $.ajax({

                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/Institutions/Create/GetProvinceList?RegionID=" + regionID,
                    contentType: "html",

                    success: function (response) {
                        debugger
                        $("#ProvinceID").empty();
                        $("#ProvinceID").append(response);

                    }
                })
            })
        })
</script>
}
```

*Shared/ProvinceOptionPartial.cshtml*

```
<option value="">--Select Province--</option>

@if(ViewBag.ProvinceeOptions != null)
{
    foreach (var item in ViewBag.ProvinceOptions )
    {
        <option value="@item.Value">@item.Text</option>

    }
}
```

## The Result

[After Selecting a Region and  Pressing F10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q2lGQ.png)

## The Question

From what I understand, the statements in my script within my ajax call are being ignored for some reason. To be honest, I do not know what the url does but I've imitated it the same as the video I watched based on my own structure. And I've already played around the IDs for my Dropdownlists. Any form of help or advice will be greatly appreciated. I honestly wouldn't mind if I look like an idiot right now because I'm too desperate already! Help!

Comment: The very first thing you need to understand is that your editing data so you use view models, not your data models. And no one is going to wade through all this (90% of what you have shown is irrelevant to the question - refer [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Then suggest you study the code in [this DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1bPZym)

Comment: What's the point using `$("#ProvinceID").append(response);`? I think you need to use `$.each(response, function(...))` to append DDL items instead. I suggest you read this first: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40726070/mvc-cascading-dropdown-using-jquery-ajax.

Comment: Sorry about that, I now have edited my question as much as I can and studying all of your answers at the moment, thanks!